# Select button elements based on appearing text in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

(EDIT:
I forgot to ask to not use jQuery)

---

I'm trying to select html buttons based on their displayed text, not their class or id.

All the button have the same dom structure and classes. Like `follow` and `unfollow` buttons in the folowing example:

```
<button class="user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn" type="button">
  <span class="button-text following-text">
     Following
  </span>
  <span class="button-text unfollow-text">
     Unfollow
  </span>
</button>
```

The closest solution I found is based on the dom structure like `getElementsByClassName`, `getElementById` and `:contains()`, but I can't figure it out.

EDIT2:
The solution in jQuery would be `$('span:hidden:contains(Follow)').parent();`
but I'm searching for a solution without jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code, you can style accordingly

```
$( "span:nth-child(1):contains('Following')" ).css( "background", "#ccc" );
```

Comment: Yep, `:contains()` pretty much does it. +1

Comment: Every button has a span which contains 'Following'. I tried it already.

Comment: with the help of nth-child selector style accordingly

Comment: You are selecting the spans, which are present in every `button`. Hence those spans are not always displayed and what I asked is how to to get the parent `button` which displays one of those spans.

Answer (score 0):

you can give id's to spans as follows:

```
  <span id="follow" class="button-text following-text">
     Following
  </span>
  <span id="unfollow" class="button-text unfollow-text">
     Unfollow
  </span>
```

and then by using the below code in javascript, you can check their status

```
if(document.getElementById("follow").innerHTML=="Following"){
//follow 
}
if(document.getElementById("unfollow").innerHTML=="Unfollow"){
//unfollow 
}
```

Comment: I don't need to get those spans. I can get them with `contains()`. I need to get the parent `button` :)

Comment: what finally you want to do with button?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it with `:hidden` but this is jQuery and thus not useful in my case.

```
$('span:hidden:contains(Follow)').parent();
```

The best thing I found now is to get all buttons first and then use a condition (takes 2 steps, but working).

```
var buttons=document.getElementsByClassName('...');
//loop...
    if ( window.getComputedStyle(buttons[i].getElementsByClassName('...')[0] ).display === 'none' ) {
        //buttons[i]
    }
```

If you find a better solution it's still welcome :-)